# Which is the smallest space $X\subset L^{2}$ where the conservation law holds in the norm of $X$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

We formally write the solution of nonlinear Schrödinger equation (NLS) as follows:

$$u(t)= U(t-t_{0}) u_{0}- i \int_{t_{0}}^{t} U(t-\tau) (|u|^{2}u(\tau)) d\tau;$$
where $U(t)= e^{it\Delta} $(free Schrödinger equation), and initial data $u_{0} \in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$[For more details, see [this](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp%2FFE%2FFE_pdf_with_bookmark%2FFE21-30-en_KML%2Ffe30-115-125%2Ffe30-115-125.pdf&ei=mzwBVYCtLs2hugSgq4KoAg&usg=AFQjCNGKhLzeaJ20OTB2tApHREXUJJiZJQ&sig2=2ksKAUwK1xbEnXjeCLfRgg&bvm=bv.87920726,d.c2E) ].
It is well-known (see [Theorem 1.1](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp%2FFE%2FFE_pdf_with_bookmark%2FFE21-30-en_KML%2Ffe30-115-125%2Ffe30-115-125.pdf&ei=mzwBVYCtLs2hugSgq4KoAg&usg=AFQjCNGKhLzeaJ20OTB2tApHREXUJJiZJQ&sig2=2ksKAUwK1xbEnXjeCLfRgg&bvm=bv.87920726,d.c2E)) that for initial data $u_{0}$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb R), $ we have the conservation law in $L^{2}-$ norm: $\|u(t)\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}= \|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}$ for all time $t\in \mathbb R.$

Suppose that $X$ is a Banch space with norm $\|\cdot\|_{X}$ and $X$ is a proper subset of $L^{2}(\mathbb R).$

**My Questions** :

> (1) If we start with initial data in $X,$ then can we expect conservation law associated to the above NLS in the norm of $X,$ that is, $\|u(t)\|_{X}=\|u_{0}\|_{X}$ ?(I feel, this may be difficult, I don't know)
>
> (2)Of course, the answer of (1), depends on  $X:$ it therefore I am looking for few examples.Can we find few example of $X$ where  conservation law hold in the norm of $X$?
>
> (3) Is it true that  the space $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ is the smallest space where one can have the conservation law  hold in the space ?

**Motivation**: To prove the globe well poseness results for NLS conservation law is useful.

**Edit**: My motivation comes through this consideration:"If we have a local well posedness in $X$ for cubic NLS, then   we can expect global well posedness in $X"$ if we have a conservation law in $X$(I think). Also I am looking for explicitly $H^{1}\subset X \subset L^{2}$ where conservation law hold in $X-$norm. Kindly would you suggest me some $X$ where conservation law hold(So far papers I have been seeing every one has consider conservation in $L^{2}-$norm, I am couriers to know if we can come below $L^{2}$  )

Comment: Side remark: typically when PDE people talk about "below $L^2$" we refer to regularity classes $H^{-s}$. In your case you seem to refer to classes $H^{+s}$ which embeds in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the cubic NLS in one spatial dimension (which seems to be what you are interested in) is [completely integrable](http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/DispersiveWiki/index.php/Cubic_NLS_on_R) and has formally infinitely many conserved quantities. For example, the energy. So while I haven't checked to see whether the combinations of those conserved quantities give additional seminorms, I am highly doubtful that $L^2$ is the smallest space.

Also, the global existence theory for the cubic NLS in 1D is pretty well known (see link above), so I am not sure why you are motivated by such.

Comment: @WW; thanks; My motivation comes through this consideration:"If we have a local well posedness in $X$ for cubic NLS, then   we can expect global well posedness in $X"$ if we have a conservation law in $X$(I think). Also I am looking for explicitly $H^{1}\subset X \subset L^{2}$ where conservation law hold in $X-$norm. Kindly would you suggest me some $X$ where conservation law hold(So far papers I have been seeing every one has consider conservation in $L^{2}-$norm, I am couriers to know if we can come below $L^{2}$  ); Thanks once again

Comment: My (deleted) comment was not 100% correct. See my answer on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200331/glbobl-well-posedness-of-cubic-nls-in-for-initial-data-in-hs-mathbb-r-0s